# flex inner child wrapping order

Tags: css, flexbox

If I have elements such as the following,  the child elements of the container div will wrap first.  I would like the child elements of the items div to wrap first.  Is it possible to control the order of wrapping?

```html
<div id="container" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
  <div id="title">titletitletitletitle</div>
  <div id="items" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
    <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div>BBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, with a media query: https://jsfiddle.net/pkz4n34q/

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right, you expect the content of the sub container to wrap first.

Setting : `flex:1;` to this container, its content will wrap first untill the wrapped content takes too much width.

```html
<div id="container" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;flex-wrap: wrap">
  <div id="title">titletitletitletitle</div>
  <div id="items" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;flex-wrap: wrap; flex:1;">
     <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
     <div>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
     <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set `flex-wrap: nowrap` to container div.

```html
<div id="container" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap: nowrap">
  <div id="title">titletitletitletitle * </div>
  <div id="items" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content:space-evenly;">
     <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAA * </div>
     <div>BBBB BBBBBBBBB * </div>
     <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCC * </div>
     <div>BB BBBBBBBBBBB * </div>
     <div>CCCCCCCCC CCCC * </div>
     <div>BBBBBBBBBBBBB * </div>
     <div>CCCCCCCC CCCCC * </div>
  </div>
</div>
```